# google cloud storage pre-signed url image upload broken

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload images and pdf files from angular to google cloud storage bucket using pre-signed url. pre-signed urls created like this.

```
const [url] = await storage
      .bucket(bucketName)
      .file(objectName)
      .getSignedUrl({
        version: 'v2',
        action: 'write',
        expires: Date.now() + 604800,
        contentType: params.type,
      });
```

and then from angular files uploaded like below

```
const formData = new FormData();
let headers = new HttpHeaders();

this.allowedFiles.forEach((file, i) => {
  formData.append(
    'file',
    this.allowedFiles[i]
  );

  for (const key of Object.keys(this.headers)) {
    headers = headers.set(key, `${this.allowedFiles[i].type}`);
  }
});


const options = {
  headers,
  params,
};

this.http
  .request("PUT", pre_signed_url, {
    body: formData,
    reportProgress: true,
    observe: 'events',
    ...options,
  })
```

Upload curl example here

```
curl 'PRE_SIGNED_URL' \
  -X 'PUT' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  --data-raw $'------WebKitFormBoundaryRfPtoLnLKPcPfans\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample-image.jpeg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryRfPtoLnLKPcPfans--\r\n'
```

Image is uploaded but it's broken, but when I upload pdf it's opening correctly. Any help will be very useful.

Broken Image
[image]

Thanks

Comment: "*Image is uploaded but it's broken*"  - what does "it's broken" mean?  Please edit the question to share your specific observations that are different than what you expect.  You will need to say a lot more than just "it's not working".

Comment: @DougStevenson , Broken Image means it's not viewable in any application, it just shows broken image symbol in browser, i tried to open to see the content in file and  saw content like this ------WebKitFormBoundaryWIir2ltjUxMX7P3x